# Unexpected OCMMacroState instead of mocked object

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, storekit, ocmock

This code used to work and stopped with Xcode 8. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong, is it some premature value inside the block?

I am getting:

> failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "-[OCMMacroState productIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb07dc885a0"

While the code is:

```
OCMVerify([mockPaymentQueue addPayment:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(SKPayment *payment) {
    return [payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"testID"];
}]]);
```

Any idea how to fix it or what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this now. What happens when you rewrite the code as follows?

```
id productIdentifier = payment.productIdentifier;
OCMVerify([mockPaymentQueue addPayment:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(SKPayment *payment) {
    return [productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"testID"];
}]]);
```

Comment: The payment object is accessible inside of the block, so you can't do this ;). Anyway, I doubt it would help. In fact it was 1.5month ago, I've fixed it somehow but I already almost don't remember this problem.